# Is it possible to run Linux on ALL kind of platform?

Tags: linux, bios, 64-bit, uefi, 32-bit

We know different environment uses different kind of version of Linux, EFI has EFI ones, and Legacy has Legacy one, same for 32 and 64 bit. But is it possible to have a Linux that can run oral kind of environment?

The 32 and 64 bit difference issue is easy to solve, we all know 32-bit software can run on 64-bit hardware. But how about EFI and Legacy? Is there any kind of linux, that can run on both UEFI and Legacy mode? I know installer can run on both environment, but a installed one can't. So is there any stable Linux that can support both environment while it's still supported (not too old to have some security exploit)?

Comment: "ALL kind of platform" seems [very broad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform#Hardware_examples).

Comment: Are you actually looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64?

Comment: @tripleee I'm finding Linux that can run on both Legacy and EFI mode without switching them in BIOS

Comment: You either run Legacy, or run EFI. Not both. If you want a Linux installer that can somehow detects the BIOS setting (EFI / Legacy) and install the correct one accordingly - then yes it does exist.

Answer (score 2):

"All kinds of platforms"? There are *dozens* of platforms that Linux runs on, and you seem to be only talking about two of them. "UEFI" isn't just for x86/x64 – it's also used by other CPU architectures such as IA64 and arm64. It is impossible to have a single Linux kernel which runs on x64 and arm64, for example.

But can you have a Linux installation that runs on x86 in both "Legacy" and "UEFI" modes? **Yes.** Linux doesn't actually *care* all that much – 90% of the differences only affect the boot process (i.e. things which happen *before* Linux is started). The CPU architecture doesn't actually change, so the same Linux kernel and software will work.

All you need for dual compatibility with x86 BIOS and x86/x64 UEFI is to install two bootloaders to the system disk (they can be different, e.g. grub+elilo or syslinux+refind).

Comment: Then how to achieve it, since I've heard someone that you can't install two boot loader on one linux